# how can I use the photos in drawable directory properly

Tags: android

when I put an image in ***drawable*** directory the app works in virtual imulator but it doesnt work on a real device but when i put the same image in ***raw*** directory the app works well in both virtual and real device
whats the  reason for that ??

```js
06-17 13:50:03.699 32575-32575/com.example.alaaphotoarrange1986 E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2', referenced from method androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.addOnUnhandledKeyEventListener
06-17 13:50:03.699 32575-32575/com.example.alaaphotoarrange1986 E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.WindowInsets', referenced from method androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.dispatchApplyWindowInsets
06-17 13:50:03.749 32575-32575/com.example.alaaphotoarrange1986 E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.WindowInsets', referenced from method androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.onApplyWindowInsets
06-17 13:50:03.749 32575-32575/com.example.alaaphotoarrange1986 E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener', referenced from method androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.removeOnUnhandledKeyEventListener
06-17 13:50:03.819 32575-32575/com.example.alaaphotoarrange1986 E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$1', referenced from method androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener
06-17 13:50:03.959 32575-32575/com.example.alaaphotoarrange1986 E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
06-17 13:50:04.019 32575-32575/com.example.alaaphotoarrange1986 E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.textclassifier.TextClassificationManager', referenced from method androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextClassifierHelper.getTextClassifier
06-17 13:50:05.039 32575-32575/com.example.alaaphotoarrange1986 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f06005f
        at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1884)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1521)
        at android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(View.java:14361)
        at com.example.alaaphotoarrange1986.MainActivity.display(MainActivity.java:109)
        at com.example.alaaphotoarrange1986.MainActivity.access$400(MainActivity.java:17)
        at com.example.alaaphotoarrange1986.MainActivity$1.onGlobalLayout(MainActivity.java:82)
        at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnGlobalLayout(ViewTreeObserver.java:682)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1887)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1143)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4667)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: what api is you phone?

Comment: Which api is your emulator and real device are working? Also could you please post what you have tried to do.

Comment: emulator api 25.... the real device 16 .. the app minimum api 16

Comment: What is the image format/extension?

Comment: I am using png and am tried jpg but the same result came

Answer (score -1):

If your api is higher to 21, you should request permission to read images folder

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // Permission is not granted
    }
```

Comment: min api is set to be 16, i tried the app on devices api 16, 18, 20 but the same result

Comment: can you post the error in the consola when you try to use the photo?

Comment: I added it in the main question (I added Log.e but it didnt showed as an error apperly

Comment: can you show me how you get the resource?. You don't find Resource ID #0x7f06005f